# Mirroring and logs

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

we have mirroring on our live database and we will updating live hardware.
I will be failing over to our DR box.

1. Do I need to stop mirroring AFTER failing over, or do I let it continue checking for the mirror?
2. Does mirroring also send over any log files?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your contribution/participation. However, the community does expect a certain quality in the questions and answers posted. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question is missing a full explanation (missing details) and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/217520/edit) your question and add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the hardware will require the server to be down.

You should :

1. Failover to DR node.
2. Change mirroring mode from sync to async - if mirroring is set to Sync mode.
3. Pause mirroring on the new Primary.
4. Perform maintenance - upgrade hardware.
5. Resume mirroring - all the accumulated transactions will be sent once you "unpause" mirroring. There will be a spike in network usage.

** Make sure you take transaction log backups on a frequent basis. Also, work on the plan of - what if the only primary goes down while you are upgrading your DR ?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, its much appreciated.